# How work the loadDataWithBaseURL method?

Tags: android

My code is behaving strangely. I have the "asstest" folder and therein screen.png file. And i have  MainActiviy with code:

```
package webviewtest.webviewtest;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        String data = "<html><body><img src=\"screen.png\" style=\"display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;position:relative;top:50%;margin-top:-101px;\"></body></html>";
        view.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
}
```

And it work. But I use "android_asset" instead of "android assetS", while my folder called "assetS", why does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is taken from URLUtil class in the Android source:

```
public final class URLUtil {
private static final String LOGTAG = "webkit";
// to refer to bar.png under your package's asset/foo/ directory, use
// "file:///android_asset/foo/bar.png".
static final String ASSET_BASE = "file:///android_asset/";
```

Later there is a check weather it's an asset url:

```
/**
 * @return True iff the url is an asset file.
 */
public static boolean isAssetUrl(String url) {
    return (null != url) && url.startsWith(ASSET_BASE);
}
```

[URLUtil.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/core/java/android/webkit/URLUtil.java)

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The android_asset folder is populated from whichever folder(s) you designate as your asset folder in the gradle build file.

```
android.sourceSets.main { assets.srcDirs = ['assets'] }
```

See: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure